# Postgres Many to many mapping sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

Postgresql Database

```
Table User
-----------
ID | Name

1  | John
2  | Bob
3  | Sarah


Table Photo
-------------
ID | Caption

1   | Vacation
2   | Birthday
3   | Christmas

Table Comment
--------------
ID | User ID | Photo ID| Text

1  |    1    |    1    | Mexico Looks Great
2  |    2    |    1    | Sure Does
3  |    3    |    1    | Too Hot
4  |    1    |    2    | Look at that cake
5  |    3    |    2    | No ice cream?
6  |    1    |    3    | So Happy
```

Desire: I want to get all the photos that ONLY John(1) and Sara(3) commented on.

How do I build a SQL query that looks for photos that only have comments from user #1 and user #3, I want to EXCLUDE results where more(or less) than those two commented on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearest and most readable way, is the `Photo`s containing comments by:

User1 `Intersect` User2 `Except` Any other user

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dc786/3) and query will return that:

```
SELECT *
FROM Photo
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT "Photo ID" FROM Comment WHERE "User ID" = 1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT "Photo ID" FROM Comment WHERE "User ID" = 3
    EXCEPT
    SELECT "Photo ID" FROM Comment WHERE "User ID" NOT IN (1, 3)
)
```

Comment: This one seemed the most concise. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

lets do three joins, one for john, one for sara, one for everyone else. Then we'll limit what we get back with the where clause.

```
select p.*
from photo p
left join comment john on john.photo_id=p.photo_id and john.user_id=1
left join comment sara on sara.photo_id=p.photo_id and sara.user_id=3
left join comment everyone_else on everyone_else.photo_id=p.photo_id and everyone_else.user_id<>3 and everyone_else.user_id<>1
where 
everyone_else.id is null
and john.id is not null
and sara.id is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  One is to use `count` with `case`:

```
select photoid
from comment
group by photoid
having count(distinct userid) = 2
  and count(case when userid not in (1,3) then 1 end) = 0
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0d0e/3)

Basically, make sure 2 users have commented and then make sure only user 1 or 3 commented.

Comment: what if user 3 comments twice and user 1 once. It should still come back, right?

Comment: @Andreas -- why the downvote? did you not notice the word `DISTINCT`?  Here is an updated fiddle with userid commenting twice: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ec846/1

Answer (score -1):

You could use an intersection to find only the common photos, which would exclude photos commented by John but not Sarah, or vice versa

```
select photo_id from comment where user_id = 1
intersect
select photo_id from comment where user_id = 3
```